# Screen flicker issues on a Razer Blade 15 mid 2019 Nvidia 2060 RTX build running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen, flicker

I setup Ubuntu 18.04 on my Razer Blade 15, mid 2019 with **Nvidia 2060 RTX** GPU using these [instructions](https://medium.com/@luca.diliello/setting-up-razer-blade-15-inch-2019-oled-version-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-86181ff8892f)

Beside the WIFI it worked all fine.

But then the screen (randomly) started to flicker when I tried to connect it to a HDMI Device. I have used many other Devices to watch movies or do some work on an external Monitor. I had these flicker issues when trying to setup Ubuntu the first time, but after reinstalling they were gone.

Since I am using the notebook for a few months now, Im looking for a way to resolve this issue without having to backup & reinstall everything.

I tried several ways to update or reinstall the nvidia drivers, but so far nothing worked out as expected.

[I tried this to update and install the recommended drivers](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04)

But as you can see, my system do not even correctly detect my graphics card model any more

```
sudo lshw -c display
    [sudo] password for thedoc: 
      *-display                 
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: NVIDIA Corporation
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           logical name: /dev/fb0
           version: a1
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
           configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
           resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:181 memory:57000000-57ffffff memory:6030000000-603fffffff memory:6040000000-6041ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:58000000-5807ffff
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: Intel Corporation
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
           resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:179 memory:6043000000-6043ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

After that I tried today to uninstall and reinstall all nvidia related packages, including cuda and libcudnn using [this](https://medium.com/@exesse/cuda-10-1-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-d04f89287130).
Afterwards I had some unmet dependencies which I tried to repair using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* -y
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

It seemed all fine, the nvidia drivers were all installed and loaded correctly but after rebooting I instantly got the screen flicker back.

This works correctly I guess

```
    nvidia-smi
Mon Aug 17 15:00:34 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.95.01    Driver Version: 440.95.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P8     8W /  N/A |    706MiB /  5934MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1345      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            28MiB |
|    0      1598      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          25MiB |
|    0      2020      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           206MiB |
|    0      2181      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         284MiB |
|    0      2583      G   ...uest-channel-token=16910184081649606580    48MiB |
|    0      2830      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files   108MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Currently loaded driver is nvidia-driver-440-server as it was recommended by my system and the screen flicker is heavy

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F11sv00001A58sd00002004bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d0000A370sv00008086sd00000034bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

When I disable the NVIDIA GPU and using the Intel GPU instead, everything is fine, no flickering. Therefore I believe that there is some serious issue with my driver installation.

There are also sometimes errors showing up in the notification bar which I unfortunately cannot copy and paste. But they are all 'nvidia-smi' related.

Any help is really appreciated, Im relatively new to linux as this is my first time where Im using it seriously as operating system. If I can help in any way by providing information, please tell me so.

EDIT:

**After literally months of trial and error I could finally resolve the problem**

```
xrandr --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.97
```

**my laptop is capable of 144Hz but it seems like this was too much for him lowering the refresh rate solved the issue**

Im feeling kind of relieved but also a bit dumb, a single linve solved what hours of hours struggling and reading/writing forum posts couldnt

Comment: I mention almost this exact solution in the Nvidia section of my answer. If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah thats true, but until yesterday I thought I had already done this. But only changing the monitor.xml file didnt help. 

But unfortunately my solution wasnt persistent, the flickering just showed up again the next day. I tried different refresh rates but it didnt really help. What I found out is, that lowering the screen resolution stops the flickering. But this isnt a solution for me, it seems like there isnt any more possibility left then doing a fresh installation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

There are a number of different versions of the Razer Blade 15.

In the `terminal`, type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your current BIOS version. Then go [here](http://drivers.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=350&nav=0) to check for a newer BIOS.

**Nvidia**

Confirm your settings are for a supported resolution and refresh rate. Refresh should probably be 60hz (50hz in Europe), but may be higher in some cases.

Confirm that **Secure Boot** is disabled in your BIOS, and then purge/reinstall the Nvidia drivers.

Confirm that you're using a **quality HDMI cable** to your external monitor.

There's a newer Nvidia driver available that you might try. Version 450.66, dated 8/18/2020.

It can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just checked my BIOS Version and its 1.03. On the razer web page there are no updates for my model. But a 2020 update for an advanced model which features also version 1.03. So I guess its the latest. 

I will check my options for secure boot and afterwards I will (once again) purge and reinstall the nvidia drivers. 

Would you recommend to only reinstall the drivers or should I remove and install CUDA and the cudnn library as well?

Comment: @thecodingcrow Purge both driver and CUDA and library. First just install the newer driver, retest. If it works, then reinstall the **correct** version of the CUDA/library, and that way if it starts to flicker you'll know what caused it.

Comment: @thecodingcrow Slight update to the Nvidia detail...

Comment: I will now reinstall all the nvidia stuff. Just wanted to mention that on my workstation at home there are no issues on the monitors but on my laptop screen, I use two chained monitors that are connected via displayport. On other devices where I connected via hdmi the issue persisted

Comment: @thecodingcrow Confirm that you're using a quality HDMI cable.

Comment: I dont use hdmi connection for my workstation, the displayport is working fine (until now)

After purging all nvidia related stuff, disabling the noveu driver I am currently stuck at following point:

I have successfully installed the nvidia drivers 450.66, nothing else, BUT
The drivers wont load, I rebooted many times now but it says nvidia-smi fails to communicate with the driver

secure boot is enabled bc when I disable it my laptop gets stuck in a boot loop

So, my question is how do I get the nvidia drivers loaded after installing it when a reboot doesnt do the job? 
@heynnema

Comment: @thecodingcrow I wouldn't have disabled the nouveau driver. Anyway, because your hardware is so new, you might need to try 20.04.1. Build a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and try that. Report back.

Comment: I will try again tomorrow, now I got some work to do and on my external monitors its working fine anyway

I just tried to install the nvidia-driver-450 package, via .run file as well as from the ppa repository. It worked in some cases and in some not, but every single time it worked the flicker was back instantly after booting, even in the boot screen. 

Noveu drivers were disabled and enabled, secure boot was mostyl disabled but sometimes I had to re-enable it in order to escape from bootloop (with flicker)

Comment: Currently secure boot is enabled, I was able to start the machine and drivers are loaded correctly (nvidia-smi is working). No cud-toolkit installed. Thinking about opening an issue on the nvidia developer forum

Comment: @thecodingcrow Try the Ubuntu Live 20.04.1 USB first.

Comment: After literally months of trial and error I could finally resolve the problem

xrandr --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.97

my laptop is capable of 144Hz but it seems like this was too much for him
lowering the refresh rate solved the issue

Comment: @thecodingcrow Wow! Thanks for the update. I mention that very possibility in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had terrible screen flickering with the razer blade 15 when I switched to dedicated Nvidia graphics.

The syslogs showed : [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun

I followed this advice: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/6ngsb0/razer_blade_stealth_graphics_problem/.

But in short I edited the grub file with : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux i915.enable_psr=0 i915.enable_rc6=0 button.lid_init_state=open"

Hope this helps you, I was really frustrated. Good luck.

Edit: This did apperantly not work for me. I read again through your description. The monitor you plugged in, which refresh rate does it have?
I have the feeling it is somehow related to refresh rate. I changed the refresh rate to 60hz but that did not help.

Comment: Was this the only thing you did to resolve the issue? I also stumbled across the grub file in my research, the line nearly looked like yours, but I will try.

Comment: Just tried it, for me it didnt work

Comment: hey, you are right. I guess I got confused, it worked because I switched to Intel Graphics and forgot to reboot. I will try further today. Lets keep each other updated, I think we have the same problem...

Comment: After literally months of trial and error I could finally resolve the problem 
xrandr --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.97 
my laptop is capable of 144Hz but it seems like this was too much for him lowering the refresh rate solved the issue

Comment: I first tried to change the frame rate via the ./monitors.xml file but this didnt help anything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Razer blade 15 mid 2019, on ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04. This post resolved my problem.

https://wiki.mh8.fr/doku.php?id=linux:rbs

They add this setting to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:
"intel_idle.max_cstate=4"

My current conf now looks like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=4 button.lid_init_state=open"

Where "button.lid_init_state=open" resolved another problem on my razer blade, in which closing lid would not suspend the computer.